# Cleanup on removal of dot net managed program

Tags: visual-studio, uninstallation

I would like to remove some registry entries when my program is uninstalled. Is there a way to do this directly from within Visual Studio 2008? Other way? I am creating the installer using the Publish Wizard. ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature you're looking for are custom actions.  They allow you to do pretty much anything on install and uninstall of your product.

The following link has a nice overview of how to create custom actions in Visual Studio managed deployment projects.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbd7cck3.aspx